# Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

when view in browser, i got this error:
Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'.

how should i solve this problem?

```
    Line 7:          If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    Line 8:              Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0  
    <b>Line 9:              Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)</b>
    Line 10:             'Get reference of the gridview row of the button clicked.
    Line 11:             Dim GridView2 As GridViewRow = DirectCast(btn.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
    Line 12:             Dim txt1 As TextBox = TryCast(GridView2.Cells(1).FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
```

Comment: would you share more markup and code behind?

Comment: Basically I want tO retrieve a "TextBox1" which I add in to one of the column of the gridview and indicate basic On a calculation ...so when Page load the "TextBox1" should have sow the calculated value...sO now is how am I going to retrieve that " TextBox1"

Answer (score 1):

You are working with the wrong object. Either your `sender` is your web form or `btn.Parent.Parent` is your web form. Obviously, you can't cast a web form as a button.

If this code is contained in a `Button_Click` event, then your sender is probably a button. In that case, I would change `btn.Parent.Parent` to `btn.Parent` because that is probably your grid view row if the next level up is the web form.

**UPDATE:** It looks like this is in the `Page_Load` event. In that case, the `sender` is the web form and not the button. Refer to the button name directly to fix the issue.

Comment: I want tO retrieve a "TextBox1" which I add in to one of the column of the gridview and indicate basic On a calculation ...so when Page load the "TextBox1" should have sow the calculated value...sO now is how am I going to retrieve that " TextBox1"

Answer (score 0):

You're righting this code inside the page load event in which case the sender object is the page itself and you're trying to cast that sender to a button control. The event I think is not fired because of a button but rather because of a page.

Remove this line and problem is gone

```
   <b>Line 9:              Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)</b>
```

Comment: If I remove this how am I able to retrieve that "TextBox1" in one of the column of  gridview

Comment: I asked you to remove the button retrieving line not the textbox. And I think the button has no relation ship with the retrieval of the textbox. You want to have calculated column, I think, this can be done easily in RowDataBound event of the gridview